# check for at least 2 char sequence before whitespace in javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well like the title says, how can i check it?
i have started something like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < elm.val().length; i++) {
        if (elmVal.charAt(i) !== '') {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

For example:

if the string is: "g  g  g" OR "gg g " it should be illegal.

Comment: You need to use Regex and regular expression for it.

Comment: Can you give a few examples? Like input strings and the desired output, Regular expressions sounds like what you are going to need. Add the examples to your original question (Edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string and check word one by one

```
var str = "hi how r you";
str_split = str.split(" ");
$.each(str_split,function(){
    console.log(this.length);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Samich, regular expressions is the way to go.

Learn more here:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Try this expression:

```
.{2}[\s]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if there are 2 or 1 chars and a following whitespace:

```javascript
if( elm.val().match( /\w\w?\s/ ) ){
  //do something
}
```

If you want to check if there are 2 chars before a whitespace for any whitespace:

```javascript
if( ! elm.val().match( /\W[^\s]?\s/ ) ){
  //do something
}
```

there are a few more ways to interpret your question... please specify. Its also different if you want chars AND numbers to be checked etc.

EDIT: Uuuups yep, meaned "match".. sorry

Comment: do you mean `match`, not matches? Also, your tests won't tell you if there are single characters followed by a space.

Comment: Hm.. It should have been /\w\w?\s/ and /\W[^\s]?\s/ ... yea, so its correct. Seams like I was absolutely distracted, sorry^^